# Download ZIP file from SFTP and save it to local directory

Tags: java, mule, sftp, anypoint-studio

I have a mule SFTP connector from which I want to download a ZIP file and store it locally on my computer. I am using only SFTP connector and file outbound.

The issue is that the file is somehow changed to a strange file with `.dat` extension. I assume this is because of `InputSftpStream`.

Any ideas how to download a ZIP file and save the same file without any change to computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs when file name output pattern is not defined. Please update file outbound endpoint like `outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]"` , this will create the file with the same name as the SFTP file name or you can change it to any desired pattern like `outputPattern="xyz.zip"`. Something like

```
<file:outbound-endpoint path="tmp" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

As a small workaround, you could change the file extension after the fact with:

```
File.renameTo(File dest)
```